# Score documents by the distance from the average in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with various `price` values. I want to filter these documents by something like `color:red` and rank the document by distance from the documents price to the average of the current result page.

I can use aggregation to compute the average, but the question is how can I do it in one query?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. In order to alter the score you need to use a function_score query and that query has no way of knowing what the aggregation result was. Although not completely sure, I'm 99% that this is the case